# Knaster-Tarski to show the existence of a unique fixpoint

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $\mbox{CDF}\subseteq [0,1]^{[0,\infty)}$ be the collection of cummulative distribution functions and let $T:\mbox{CDF} \rightarrow \mbox{CDF}$ be a function. We define the order $F \leq G \Leftrightarrow \forall s \in [0,\infty): F(s) \leq G(s)$. Assume we have $F \leq G \Rightarrow TF \leq TG$, I would then like to show, using Knaster-Tarski, that $T$ has a unique fix point.

I am especially interested in which extra conditions need to be imposed on $T$ to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: Are you sure you want to show it has **a unique** fix point? You could have $T$ to be the identity ($TF=F$); that would be an order-preserving function and every point would be a fix point...

Comment: Yes that is a fair point indeed! Are there some customary additional conditions to ensure uniqueness for these kind of problems?

Comment: I don't know. Actually, I don't think there are any interesting ones. Of course one could think of a family of such functions: for example, for each member $F_0$ of CDF, take the constant function $T_{F_0}$ that makes $F \mapsto F_0$. That has only one fixed point: $F_0$, and is also order-preserving (every constant map on a poset is order-preserving). But perhaps this is not what you're looking for, it doesn't seem interesting, and certainly these are not the only cases.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response it was very helpful!

Comment: Some concavity conditions might be what you are/were looking for. See, for example, https://ideas.repec.org/p/igi/igierp/604.html and the references therein.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that this set is a [partially ordered set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotallyOrderedSet.html), and not a totally ordered set. The first three properties are straightforward to show, to show that it does not satisfy the fourth property, define $X_1 \sim \textrm{N}(0,.01)$ and 
$X_2 \sim \textrm{N}(0,10)$.

We can see that at first $X_2$ has a higher CDF for $c<<0$, but because of the spikiness of $X_1$ there exists a period after $c=0$ where $X_1$ has a higher CDF.

We need to show that the partial ordered set is a [Complete Lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice) to satisfy the requirements of the [Knaster-Tarski Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem).

Suppose we have a subset of CDF's $\mathcal{C}$. We can partition $[0,\infty)$ into $[0,\infty) = \cup_{i}A_i$ where each $A_i$ is a set on which one of the $C_i \in\mathcal{C}$ has the maximal CDF value $\forall a \in A_i$. Define $C^*[a] = C_i[a]$ for $i$ such that $a \in A_i$. It is straightforward to see that $C^*$ is a least upper bound for $\mathcal{C}$. Thus supremum's always exist for all subsets.

To show infimum exist for all sets do an analogous step, but with the minimum CDF on each set $A_i$.

Thus the set of CDFs is a complete lattice, which in conjunction with the order preserving property of the operator $T$ implies that the Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem.

To use the order preserving property, we can find at least one fixed point in $F[c] = \delta_0(c)$. Because this is the maximal element of the whole space of CDFs

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your answer but what I am mainly looking for (see also the comments) is a way to make sure this fixed point is unique